# How to distinguish compound nominal predicate from predicate + AM of manner?

Tags: grammar, syntax, subordinate-clauses, subjects

I don't know how to put it right … the problem is that it's rather difficult for me to distinguish the parts of the sentence.

For example in the sentence:

> 1. *Something has gone wrong.*

I can't say if a predicate is  "**has gone**" or **"has gone wrong"**.

In the following:

> 2. *The sun was shining bright and warm*.

Is the predicate **"shining"** or **"shining bright and warm"**?

It's confusing to me that in the sentence ***"she looks happy"*** the predicate is **"looks happy"**. I would put **"looks"** as predicate and **"happy"** (looks how?- happy) as an adverbial modifier of manner, as in sentence ***"He speaks English fluently"***, **"fluently"** is an adverbial modifier.

For the example:

> 3. *For him to leave the town in early spring was an unbearable thing.*

I can't understand this, is the subject here **"for him to leave"** and the object (to leave what?) **"the town"**, or is the whole construction **"for him to leave the town in early spring"** the subject?

Sorry for the bad grammar, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Beware that you are confusing the parts of a sentence (subject, object, predicate... ) and single words (nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs...). As per your last sentence, as a general rule remember that 1) the verb refers to the subject 2) a clause should make sense with just _subject +verb (+object)_ . _to leave_ might mislead you into thinking that's the verb, but it is a noun in that context. The verb is _was_, which refers to _leaving/to leave_. That's the subject, in fact, the most basic clause you can reduce the initial sentence to is: _To leave/leaving was an unbearable thing._

Comment: So we have 2 subjects here:for him to leave and an unbearable thing? I still don't understand.

Comment: Nope, one clause, one subject. **Subject** : _To leave_. **Object:** _an unbearable thing_. Also, you may try and substitute the subject with a pronoun, as another proof : _it was and unbearable thing_. As you can see, it still makes sense.

Comment: Why not "for him to leave" like it the sentence: Is it important for you to know it?

Comment: _for him_ **completes** the meaning of the clause (in fact it is a _complement_), but it is not necessary. The subject is usually a single word. Actually, I'd put even a comma after _for him_...

Comment: @Study.English.Well Please wait for someone to give you a solid grammatical answer for your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sentence "Something has gone wrong", the subject is *something* and the predicate is *has gone wrong*. The predicate can in turn be broken down into the verb *has gone* (which is the present perfect of *go*) and the adverb *wrong*.

You can tell that *wrong* is part of the predicate, and not a sentence modifier, by the fact that you can't move it to the beginning of the sentence: *"Wrong, something has gone" would not be grammatical. So we know that *wrong* is merely modifying the verb *go*.

---

In "The sun was shining bright and warm", the situation is the same: the subject is *the sun*, and the predicate is *was shining bright and warm* (where *was shining* is the verb and *bright and warm* is an adjective phrase, or — according to some authorities — a kind of adverb phrase).

---

> It's confusing to me that in the sentence ***"she looks happy"*** the predicate is **"looks happy"**. I would put **"looks"** as predicate and **"happy"** (looks how?- happy) as an adverbial modifier of manner, as in sentence ***"He speaks English fluently"***, **"fluently"** is an adverbial modifier.

There are two problems with your reasoning here.

The first problem is that in the sentence "He speaks English fluently", you seem to be under the impression that the adverbial modifier *fluently* is not part of the predicate? But it *is* part of the predicate. The subject is *he*, and the predicate is *speaks English fluently*, where *speaks* is the verb, *English* is the direct object, and *fluently* is an adverb modifying *speaks English*.

The second problem is that in the sentence "She looks happy", the word *happy* is actually an adjective modifying *she*, rather than an adverb modifying *looks*. What's more, it's a complement, rather than an adjunct. (The verb *look* is one of a handful of verbs whose complement can be an adjective modifying the subject. Other such verbs include *seem* and *sound*: "He seemed annoyed", "You sound tired".) So "She looks happy" actually has quite a different structure than "He speaks English fluently", though in both cases the first word is the subject and the rest is the predicate.

---

In the sentence "For him to leave the town in early spring was an unbearable thing", the subject is "For him to leave the town in early spring", and the predicate is "was an unbearable thing". That subject is what's called a *small clause* or *infinitival clause*: it contains an infinitive phrase, "to leave the town in early spring", with a subject, "him". "The town" is the direct object of "to leave", and "in early spring" is an adverbial modifying "to leave the town".